# Application Crashes on Dealloc

Tags: objective-c, uiview, crash, xib

I load my view from xib. And when try to release it crashes with message:

> Designer Project(72849,0xa08c0540) malloc: *** error for object
>   0x4b06000: pointer being freed was not allocated
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug Current language: 
>   auto; currently objective-c

Here is my implementation:

```
@interface ACLine : UIView {

    NSMutableArray *chevrons;
}

- (void)addChevron:(ACChevron *)aChevron;
- (void)addChevron:(ACChevron *)aChevron atIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex;

- (void)removeAllChevrons;
- (void)removeChevron:(ACChevron *)aChevron;
- (void)removeChevronAtIndex:(NSInteger)anIndex;

- (void)update;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *chevrons;

@end

@implementation ACLine

@synthesize chevrons;

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    chevrons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    self.chevrons = nil; 
    [super dealloc]; it crashes here
}
```

Please help with solving the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try autoreleasing  chevrons.

```
 chevrons = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding "[super awakeFromNib];" after "-(void)awakeFromNib {"  ?